# Long lines in python are not getting reformatted in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

.vscode/settings.json

```json
{
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "-d",
        "C0301"
    ],
    "python.testing.unittestArgs": [
        "-v",
        "-s",
        ".",
        "-p",
        "test_*.py"
    ],
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": true,
    "[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.autopep8"
    },
    // "python.formatting.provider": "none",
    "python.formatting.provider": "autopep8",
    "python.formatting.autopep8Args": [
        "--max-line-length",
        "79",
        "--experimental"
    ]
}
```

code:

```py
if (1 == 10192310928301928301928301928301923 and rx_resp == 'aosidjaoisdjaoisdjaoisjdaoisjdaoisjdaoisjd' and 44 == 11111):
            print('aoisjdoaijsdoiajsdoaisjdoaijsdoaisjdoaisjdaoisjdiasjdoajaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa')
```

No error shown on these long lines. When I click on format I should see some error saying line too long or linter should automatically break lines into shorter format.

Comment: Linters don't reformat your code, they just point out problems. You're talking about a formatter.

Comment: I tried it myself using autopep8 on the command line and it also doesn't break the lines. Maybe it's version-specific behaviour or there's some other option you need to enable?

Comment: I did a quick google (`autopep8 break long lines`), and it looks like autopep8 only breaks long lines in "obvious and safe cases"

Comment: Auto formatters cannot solve all your problems. Some things you have to format manually. Also, formatters typically don't report errors. They just format as best as they can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `Black Formatter` extension.

set `.vscode/settings.json` file as follows:

```
{
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.testing.unittestArgs": [
        "-v",
        "-s",
        ".",
        "-p",
        "test_*.py"
    ],
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": true,
    "[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter",
        "editor.formatOnSave": true
    },
    "black-formatter.args": [
        "--line-length",
        "79"
    ]
}
```

Now long lines in python will get reformatted on save.

Answer (score -1):

settings.json

```json
{
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.testing.unittestArgs": [
        "-v",
        "-s",
        ".",
        "-p",
        "test_*.py"
    ],
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": true,
    "[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.autopep8"
    },
    "python.formatting.provider": "none"
}
```

I uninstalled pylint extension.

Now some basic formatting works.
eg: `status  =status.HTTP_200_OK` after formatting will become `status=status.HTTP_200_OK`

Comment: How does this answer the question? You might want to read [answer].

Comment: There is no difference between the before and after in the example.

Comment: spacing has changed